# security issue, when an json element contains html?

Tags: javascript, json, security, exploit

Will it become to an security issue, when the content of an element has html in it ?

Like:

```
 "element": "<li role=\"presentation\" class=\" \"><a href=\"#...\" aria-controls=\"...\" role=\"tab\" data-toggle=\"tab\">...</a></li>",
```

or:

```
"element": "<iframe src='/structure/.../....html' width='100%' height='400px'  frameborder='0'   scrolling='no' marginheight='0'    marginwidth='0'></iframe>"
```

This would be send to a client.

Answer (score 2):

Not intrinsically.

If the HTML was subject to XSS injection or otherwise contained malicious code and then the recipient of the JSON parsed it, extracted the HTML and then inserted the HTML into a document: Then you would have a problem.

Comment: Good answer, although the recipient would have the problem (and also the solution) .